# Bootstrap and Sass: error when converting SCSS files to CSS. Error: Undefined variable @each $color, $value in $theme-colors-rgb

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-5

I would like to shrink the size of the bootstrap file `bootstrap.min.css`. I've found that a good way to do this is to use SASS, then SCSS, so I can import only the specific components I need. I've never used them, only used CSS so far. I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap, and I'm downloading the Sass [source files][1] in Bootstrap.

When I try to convert scss file to css, I get an error. I've already read several solutions on stackoverflow (example import `@import "../scss/bootstrap/maps";`), but they didn't help me. Here is the error:

```
Error: Undefined variable.
    ╷
21 │ @each $color, $value in $theme-colors-rgb {
    │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
   scss/bootstrap/_root.scss 21:27 @import
   scss/custom.scss 16:9 root stylesheet
```

The path is `Desktop/myproject/scss/bootstrap`. These are the steps I performed:

1. In the project, I added scss folder. Inside I created a folder called bootstrap where all the ssc files are present. So `myproject/scss/bootstrap` (downloaded from above link).
2. In the project, I added a file called custom.scss. So `myproject/scss/custom.scss`

3.In the `custom.scss` file (i only have this in custom, then there is nothing left in the file), I added the name of the components I need:

```
@import "../scss/bootstrap/functions";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/variables";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/mixins";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/root";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/reboot";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/type";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/images";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/containers";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/grid";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/offcanvas";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/navbar";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/card";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/dropdown";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/list-group";
@import "../scss/bootstrap/nav";
```

4. I try to convert the `custom.scss` file into `bootstrap.min-news.css`, then in the Visual Studio terminal I write: `sass scss/custom.scss:css/bootstrap.min-new.css`

How can i convert the file without getting the error? Thank you

**P.S: If I also try to import `@import "../scss/bootstrap/maps";`, I get the error:**

```
Error: Undefined variable.
    ╷
55 │ "primary": $primary-text-emphasis-dark,
    │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**UPDATE**

Instead if I import `@import "../scss/bootstrap/variables-dark"`, the problem is solved and the compilation takes place correctly, but I DONT'T want to use variables-dark, I don't need it, the file size increases unnecessarily. My goal is to reduce the size

Comment: Very weird, using bootstrap 5.2.3 from [5.2 scss importing docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/#importing), this seems to be compiling OK but sporadically gets another odd undefinided sass var, but this codesandbox seems to be stable atm... https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-5-2-scss-importing-tvzmqr

Comment: I get the same error first time but if I refresh the browser test after initial load it works... not sure why that is...

Comment: This is a known breaking change introduced going from 5.2.3 > 5.3 [github issue talking about the breaking change](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/38683)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I tested this very basic [`bootstrap 5.2.3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap/v/5.2.3) npm install compiling scss.

Which is taken from 5.2 docs, see commented version in doc version...

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/#importing

This order of scss imports compiles fine for me...

```scss
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/helpers";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

---

However if I run the same scss above in [`bootstrap 5.3.0`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap/v/5.2.3) I get this error...

```txt
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
55 │     "primary": $primary-text-emphasis-dark,
   │                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

So I checked the docs for 5.3, and there is addition of variables dark scss...

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/#importing

```scss
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/helpers";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

Compiling the scss above for 5.3 now works.

---

**Update 1**

So the code provided above is bare minimum for the bootstrap css framework to work.

You then start to add the extra components after utilities like this...

```scss
// core files
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/helpers";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";

// extra components
@import "bootstrap/scss/offcanvas";
@import "bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/nav";
```

The above code compiles css at 180 kib.

If you're still struggling with compiled size being to big, you can remove colours from the `$theme-color` maps...

```scss
// core files
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";

// remove colours
$theme-colors: map-remove($theme-colors, "body", "secondary", "tertiary", "emphasis", "border", "primary", "danger", "warning", "info", "light", "dark");

// core files continued
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/helpers";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";

// extra components
@import "bootstrap/scss/offcanvas";
@import "bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "bootstrap/scss/nav";
```

This compiles at 167 kib.

But you probably don't want to remove every colour especially the shades, for example you might just do the colours...

```scss
$theme-colors: map-remove($theme-colors, "info", "light", "dark");
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Update 2**

For example, if you are using `@import "bootstrap/scss/alerts";` this will create these classes in your compiled css...

```txt
.alert-primary
.alert-secondary
.alert-success
.alert-danger
.alert-warning
.alert-info
.alert-light
.alert-dark
```

By using `map-remove` like this...

```scss
$theme-colors: map-remove($theme-colors, "primary", "secondary", "info", "light", "dark");
```

This will then compile only these alert colours...

```txt
.alert-success
.alert-danger
.alert-warning
```

This will do the same for anything that uses the `$theme-colors` map to generate colour variants of components.

If you are not using a colour, you can remove from the `$theme-colors` map and it will reduce the size of your css and speed up compiling slightly.

Comment: PART 1: I'm using Bootstrap 5, downloaded from the link in my question. Why did you notice that my original code looks like Bootstrap 4? Anyway I did what you suggested and the compilation works fine, but that's not what I wanted to achieve. There are some things I don't need and the file grows in size. Original Bootstrap.min.css is 220 kb, while the one generated with your answer (without my offcanvas, navbar, card, etc) is 125 kb. For example variables-dark I don't need, as well as a few other things. I weigh down the file unnecessarily.

Comment: PART 2: As per the post question, why am I getting 21 │ each $color, $value in $theme-colors-rgb? I don't want to fix using import variables-dark. I wanted to create this compiled file, just to reduce the size of the bootstrap-min.css file and get to 70-80-90 kb. Do you have any other ideas on how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: @Folidexman I've added update 1 to answer. Ignore my comment on boostrap 4 code I was mistaken. I think variables-dark is new to bootstrap 5.3. I don't think it will work with out it now. But variables dark is only there to handle reversed styles when toggled from lightmode to darkmode.

Comment: @joshomoto All right. Thank you. A curiosity. What is this you wrote for? Why should I add it? It's important? // remove colours
$theme-colors: map-remove($theme-colors, "body", "secondary", "tertiary", "emphasis", "border", "primary", "danger", "warning", "info", "light", "dark");

Comment: @joshmoto I commented above, but this is important to your answer, here's the thread on BS github talking about the breaking change: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/38683

Comment: @disinfor sweet as I thought, this is a mandatory include now from 5.3. 

Comment: @Folidexman see update 2 in my answer 

Comment: @joshmoto yeah, it's been a plague on our internal builds for a bit now. We literally had a team meeting about this issue yesterday and how we all overcome it. I don't know if we came to a consensus on a fix beyond - "I guess we keep dark variables". haha!

Comment: @disinfo I guess it is what it is, tho pretty cool for straight up bootstrap theming if you got a light/dark mode button switch. Not had a chance to play with it yet tho.

Comment: @joshmoto Can you help me with the link question? It's about the same code as this answer. Excuse me for tagging you to tell you this, but I'm losing hope that anyone can answer me. I will gladly accept your answer if you help me. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76631426/how-can-i-minimize-the-bootstrap-min-css-file-by-selecting-and-converting-scss-c